# PL/SQL to translate a number into text

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, jasper-reports

Im using Jaspersoft iReport tool for designing a report from a table in Oracle DB.
I am getting a value in number, I want to convert it into text.

Like for example if the value im getting is  **1652**  i need a Pl/SQL function to translate it into **One Thousand Five Hundred and Two**

Is there any functions available?

Comment: Ignore the fact that the duplicate suggestion is about converting to Italian.  It includes the solution for spelling numbers are words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can convert the number to a timestamp and back to get this for integers:

```
SQL>    select to_char(to_timestamp(lpad( 1652 , 9, '0'), 'FF9' ), 'Ffsp' ) str
  2    from dual;

STR
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
One Thousand Six Hundred Fifty-Two

SQL> select to_char(to_timestamp(lpad( 1502 , 9, '0'), 'FF9' ), 'Ffsp' ) str from dual;

STR
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
One Thousand Five Hundred Two
```

which would work up to a certain extent (the size of the string it will return is limited). otherwise you'd have to write your own function to do this.

Comment: Nice trick! It starts failing with `ORA-01877: string is too long for internal buffer` with very big numbers, the largest I've seen that works is 999,999,099.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp yeah the limit is a 75 character output using this method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this trick:

```
DECLARE 
   ws_number NUMBER := 30; 
   ws_text   VARCHAR2(60); 
BEGIN 
   ws_text := to_char(to_date(ws_number,'j'), 'jsp'); 
 END;
```

the `j` converts the number to a Julian date and the `jsp` returns the value of the Julian date. It's described more fully on [this Ask Tom post](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3aNO%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:18305103094123#PAGETOP)

Comment: Ty Ben, i cant use enter on the code, dont know why.

Comment: You need a / after executing an anonymous pl/sql block inside sql*plus

Comment: This works for numbers 1 to 5,373,484.